# Как добавить button в SearchVIew?

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design

как реализовать добавление Button в SearchView?

```
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/actionSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marginConstraintLayoutOnBothSides"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marginConstraintLayoutOnBothSides"
    android:background="@drawable/background_search_view"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:queryBackground="@null"
    android:queryHint="@string/search"
    android:searchHintIcon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_close"
    android:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" >


</SearchView>
```

**[image: пример]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот решение

```
 LinearLayout llSearchView = (LinearLayout) actionSearch.getChildAt(0);
llSearchView.addView(buttonNew);
```

**actionSearch** - ваш SearchView (findByViewId(R.id.actionSearch))

**buttonNew** - кнопка которую нужно добавить